# Potential Issues and downfalls of the "honeyPot" in asp.net mvc

Tags: honeypot, asp.net-mvc, bot

Within the last few weeks I have been noticing massive amounts of bot traffic coming out of a small geographical area. I have implemented the robots.txt into my ASP.net project, but as I understand it, this is only intended to guide non-malicious bots. So far, i have not had any actual penetration issues, but I am seeing more and more malicious traffic from the same locations, and different IP addresses. I would like to implement the honeypot to prevent some of this, but I am concerned about the method itself. Is this considered a safe method, and are there any potential security risks associated with adding this to my site? especially if I am logging the hits? Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sold on needing to use ASP?

Comment: @MikeSchem It would be very preferable, this is a large site that we are constantly working on, I would prefer to have a "roll your own" solution to implement, so I can make changes as necessary, and have more control over implementation, and execution. Since we are getting pretty constant requests to make changes.

Comment: what about a netcat script?